# How to use "Default persistence enforce" at project level

Tags: codefluent

I've set property "Default persistence enforce" at project level to **true**. Then I set a relationship to "Default persistence enforce" to **false** between User and association. When I navigate from one relation to another, my property remains setted to **false**.

Now when I run the producers:

- My property is reverted to true
- Generated code shows me a CHECK CONSTRAINT, instead of a NO CHECK
- Constraint generated in pivot appears as `check="true"`

Is it possible to enforce the "Default persistence enforce" property to true at project level and deactivate certain relationship ?

Thanks for your answer,

Below the model part

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="WcfServices.Model" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1" xmlns:cfom="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.model/2005/1" xmlns:cfsps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlpivotscript/2013/1" defaultPersistenceEnforce="true" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:entity name="Association" namespace="Example.Model.Association" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="AssociationId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Label" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Users" typeName="Example.Model.Association.UserCollection" relationPropertyName="Association" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration produceViews="true" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.persistence" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.persistence\WcfServices.persistence.sqlproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update, DontRemove" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer name="Business Object Model (BOM)" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom">
    <cf:configuration compileWithVisualStudio="true" compile="false" codeDomProviderTypeName="CSharp" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.model" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.model\WcfServices.model.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update">
      <subProducer typeName="Ixcys.Producers.ServiceModelProducer.ServiceProducer, Ixcys.Producers.ServiceModelProducer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" compileWithVisualStudio="true" compile="false" codeDomProviderTypeName="CSharp" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.proxy" silverlightTargetVersion="Unspecified" jsonOptions="EnableJson" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.web\WcfServices.web.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
    </cf:configuration>
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="User" namespace="Example.Model.Association" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="UserId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Name" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Association" typeName="Example.Model.Association.Association" relationPropertyName="Users" />
    <cf:property name="Adresses" typeName="Example.Model.Association.AddressCollection" relationPropertyName="User" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server Pivot Script" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlPivotScriptProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.web" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.web\WcfServices.web.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="Address" namespace="Example.Model.Association" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="AddressId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Line" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="User" typeName="Example.Model.Association.User" relationPropertyName="Adresses" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
</cf:project>
```

The generated SQL is given below

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Use_Us__Ass_Ass] FOREIGN KEY (
 [User_Association_AssociationId]
) REFERENCES [dbo].[Association](

 [Association_AssociationId]
)
```

Comment: It's a bug referenced WI-7628. You can subscribe to [this RSS feed](http://www.codefluententities.com/rss.aspx) to get notified of bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer